# codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to write CodeIgniter query having MAX, SUBSTRING and CAST together that returns an integer value.. 
This is what I have in the module passing a prefix (AL, PK etc):

```
function getMaxIDMatchingPrefix($locationPrefix){ 
 $sql = "SELECT MAX( SUBSTRING( locationID , 3, 11 ) ) 
 FROM items WHERE LEFT( locationID , 2 ) = = ? "; 
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, $locationPrefix); 
 return $query; 
}
```

This is what I have in the controller to retrieve the integer value (1 or 3 or 114 etc):

```
$location_max_id = $this->location_model->getMaxLocationID($locationPrefix);
```

But I get an error: **Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string** Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> `$query->result_array()` returns an
>   array of arrays, you would use
>   `$sale['name']` in a foreach loop.
>
> `$query->result()` returns an array of
>   stdclass objects, you would use
>   `$sale->name` in a foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I tried $query->result() method it still doesnt work, it throws an error: Trying to get property of non-object.
Any other ideas please?

Comment: @pks That may mean your query is incorrect. Does it run on its own?

Comment: `$sql="select count(*) as test from table";
 $q=$this->db->query($sql)->result();
  foreach ($q as $row) {
   $data = $row;
  }
 echo $data->test;`

Comment: @Anther the query itself runs fine but not when I intergrate it with CodeIgnier

Comment: When I tried your method it got rid of the error but returns nothing :(